# How do I capture the drop event in the background of my control?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a bunch of controls of the same type on one screen and am trying to implement drag and drop to change the order of the items.

The drag and drop logic I wrote works fine, my problem is that my control has a bunch of whitespace. Everything is enclosed in a border, but about 50% of that area is not filled with more sub-controls.

In the following image, the pen is my cursor, and it shows me I can drop on the image.

[image: image showing a pen as cursor when hovering an image while dragging an item]

The cursor turns into a pen for every control inside the border (the image, the text, the green and red buttons on the bottom, and the orange dot in the top right corner)

In this image, the red cross is my cursor, and it shows me I cannot drop it on the background inside the border.

[image: image showing a red cross as cursor when hovering the background of my control]

The cursor turns into a red cross in any place where the background can be seen.

How do I make sure the whole area inside the border is considered a drop-area?

Comment: Could you share the XAML code for the picture you provided?

Comment: The shape of the cursor and where you can drop is based on the DragEnter event handler.  We can't see it.

Comment: You must handle DragDrop.DragOver or DragDrop.GiveFeedback event (or  the tunneling version). This allows to identify the element that the object is currently dragged over in order to e.g. change the cursor to give feedback. Then handle the actual Drop event in the parent container element of the drop target area in case that there is only a single drop target within the area. If there are multiple valid drop targets each must handle Drop on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed that there was no background inside my custom control. I fixed it by filling the border with a transparent background rectangle:

```
<local:MyCustomControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Client"
    x:Class="MyNamespace.Client.Controls.MyCustomControl"
    Margin="2" Padding="0" Height="Auto" Foreground="Black" AllowDrop="True">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=border}" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=border}" Fill="Transparent"></Rectangle>
        <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="LightGray" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >
            <!-- content goes here -->
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</local:MyCustomControl>
```